# Best Practices for Monitoring Log Files

Tags: security, monitoring, logs

What are the best practices for monitoring log files on a single Ubuntu Server (LAMP)?

Are there any specific "go-to" files that should be watched?

I use fail2ban to monitor failed logins, but am looking for other things to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 0):

To view logfiles [Multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/features.php) is quite nice!

And if you want to know more about the Apache Logfiles here are some interesting links:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/logs/#.UTFNx1Fx2PI

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html